# In linear regression, why after normalization of both x and y, the slope becomes cor(x, y)?

Tags: regression, correlation, normalization

If we normalize (scale and center) `x` and `y`, then the slope from `y_norm ~ x_norm` is equal to `cor(x, y)`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because, *by definition*  `y_norm` and `x_norm` are unit-variance random variables whose *covariance* is related to the *covariance* of $X$ and $Y$ by $$\operatorname{cov}\left(\frac{X-\mu_X}{\sigma_X},\frac{Y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}\right) = \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}.$$
Now apply the definition of `cor(x,y)`.

Comment: My question is very similar to:

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183778/apparent-contradiction-in-inverting-linear-regression

Comment: Not sure how to do a newline here! Anyways, I'm still not sure how the slope becomes equal to the correlation. And also the answers to the above post are not very clear. I came upon this problem when I was trying both `y_norm ~ x_norm` and `x_norm ~ y_norm`, and to my surprise, the slope were the same.

Comment: See [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20553/6633) and its answers.

Answer (score 0):

cor(x, y)=Cov(x,y)/Sd(x)sd(y)  when you standardize....  your standard deviation of x and y will equal to 1 and therefore you will have 1 on your denominator and your cor(x,y) = cov(x,y)

Comment: I understand this, but my whole question is why cov(x, y) is the same as slope of y ~ x.